# How to dynamically provide the size of a list in python and how to distribute the values in a specified range in python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, grouping, ocr, distribution

I have a user to input list values which can be anything like 1 0.95 0.9 0.7 0.6
The numbers will be in decreasing order always and the numbers below 0.6 will always be considered as less than 0.6. Now I have a list of values ranging from 0-1 some 35 values and I need to divide the values in these categories.

I am having no idea on how to proceed with it, since the user can give any number of values from 0.6-1.0

I tried finding how many values are there greater than 0.6 but then don't know what to do further in order to divide the list of different values in the corresponding ranges.

This is the code I have tried to identify how many values are greater than 0.6, is there 0.6 and how many values are less than 0.6, given by the user.

```
greater = 0
equal = 0
lower = 0
for i in args['range']:
    if i > 0.6:
        greater += 1
    elif i == 0.6:
        equal += 1
    else:
        lower += 1
```

suppose there is a list of numbers
n = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]

and the user has given values like: 1 0.99 0.8 0.6 0.4

Now, the program should distribute the values such as

```
values_equal_to_1 = 0
values_between_0.99_and_0.8 = 1
values_between_0.6_and_0.8 = 1
values_less_than_0.6 = 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy.searchsorted` and `collections.Counter`:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

user_input = '1 0.99 0.8 0.6 0.4'
intv = sorted([float(i) for i in user_input.split() if float(i) >=0.6])
# [0.6, 0.8, 0.99, 1.0]

n = [0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]
d = Counter(np.searchsorted(sorted(intv), n, 'right'))
```

Output of `d`:

```
Counter({0: 7, 1: 1, 2: 1})
```

You can then make some representation such as :

```
{'values less than or equal to %s' % i: d.get(n,0) for n, i in 
enumerate(sorted(intv))}
```

Output:

```
{'values less than or equal to 0.6': 7,
 'values less than or equal to 0.8': 1,
 'values less than or equal to 0.99': 1,
 'values less than or equal to 1.0': 0}
```

Comment: Yup, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use list comprehensions:

```
values_equal_to_1 = len([x for x in list if x == 1])
values_between_99_and_8 = len([x for x in list if .8 < x < .99])
values_between_6_and_8 = len([x for x in list if .6 < x < .8])
values_less_than_6 = len([x for x in list if x < .6])
```

`list` is the list of values the user enters. Don't actually name it `list` as that will override built-ins

Comment: This is quiet different from what I asked but your suggestion helped me in formulating what is needed. Thanks.